# intellij , gluon mobile and scene builder tutorial?

Tags: mobile, scenebuilder, gluon

I am writing basic javafx applications with intellij and scenebuilder.
Is there any tutorial , on how to use scene builder with gluon mobile ?
Is it working on the same way with javafx ?

Answer (score 1):

Gluon mobile provides with it's extended SceneBuilder, you can find it here: http://gluonhq.com/products/

It is almost identical to regular SceneBuilder, just extended by Gluon controls.
You can use it in the same way, even connect it to your Intelij by providing the correct path go Gluon SceneBuilder in IDEA settings.